# Grails app running but unresponsive after upgrade from 2.2.4 to 2.4.2

Tags: grails

After upgrading our app from Grails 2.2.4 to 2.4.2 and working through all the dependency changes, etc., the app is running but bootstrap is not executing and no pages show up. I don't get any errors even when running with --stacktrace --verbose.  I just get the normal app running message as if all was well.  Nothing in the stacktrace.log file or the application log file.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about troubleshooting this?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Starting with sharing the `BuildConfig` will be a good idea. :)

Comment: Did you update anything other than changing the Grails version in `application.properties` and dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy? Files like Config.groovy, BuildConfig.groovy, sitemesh.xml, applicationContext.xml, some .tld files, and UrlMappings.groovy will all need updated.

Comment: @dmahapatro, It's client code so I'm not sure if I am at liberty to post it.  I will check into that.  Though the buildConfig file is over 260 lines and I've updated every dependency in it.

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey, I've updated application.properties, BuildConfig, Config, web.xml template, but haven't seen anything on .tld, applicationContext, or UrlMappings. Do you know what changes would be needed there?  Any info you can point me to? Thanks!

Comment: I would create a "clean" grails 2.4.2 then look for differences. Run `grails create-app 2-4-2-test` using Grails 2.4.2 and copy over the .tld and applicationContext files, then make sure that your UrlMappings.groovy file looks valid as well.